# vs code replace two different sides of something

Tags: regex, text, replace, visual-studio-code

suppose I have code that looks something like

```
myFunc(someInput);
```

and suppose I run this function in many different places, on many different inputs (`someInput` could be various things, I need to perserve whatever it is).

All the sudden I realize I need to perform another function on the input. So I would like to replace every instance with

```
myFunc(nutherFunc(someInput));
```

I could run a replace of `myFunc(` with `myFunc(nutherFunc(` but would have to manually close the `nutherFunc` call everywhere. is there a way, using regex or otherwise, that I can replace `myFunc(nutherFunc(` AND `))` while preservint the input?

Said another way, can I say "replace these two character sets but keep what is in between them"?

Comment: In such cases, regex is not helpful, but you may try `myFunc\(nutherFunc\((.*?)\)\);` and replace with `$1`

Comment: you mean replace .* with $1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it's the other way around, OP wants to insert the additional function. Like this I guess https://regex101.com/r/i83PR1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with a capture group to accomplish this. I'd recommend

```
myFunc\(  # match the literal characters "myFunc(" (We have to escape the paren)
(\w+)     # capture group so we can refer to the argument of `myFunc` in the replacement
\)        # a literal close paren
```

with a replacement of

```
myFunc(notherFunc($1))
```

Where the `$1` represents the group that was captured between parens.

Here's a video: https://clip.brianschiller.com/wjuWYgc-2019-12-17-replace.mp4